# JavaScript to read content between <a> tags

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Below is my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Cat website</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script12.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>
<a href="http://www.petwebsite.com/cats.asp" id="message">My_first_cat_website</a>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```
window.onload=initall;

function initall()
{
    var ans=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].firstChild.data;
    alert(ans);
    if(ans<10)
    {
        alert(ans);
    }
    var newans=ans.subString(0,9)+"...";
}
```

Here my code is not going into if block. My requirement is if var "ans" length is above 10 then append it with ... else throw an alert directly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Satya what, you ever heard of `.firstChild.data`? I haven't.

Comment: mea culpa removing my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Solution using `data` property

window.onload=initall;

```
function initall()
{
    var ans=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].firstChild.data;

    if(ans.length<10)
    {
        alert("hmmm.. its less then 10!");
    }
    var newans= ans.substring(0,9)+"...";
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].firstChild.data = newans;
}
```

Here is it live view you wise to check example: http://jsbin.com/obeleh

Comment: @rav83 what you are trying to do, like which kind of validation.

Comment: if ans variable is less than 10 chars just throw an alert directly else if more than 10 chars dispaly first ten chars and append with ...

Comment: Check it here now: http://jsbin.com/obeleh/2 , let me know if this fine i will paste the code here.

Comment: yeah tats fine..can u provide me the changes

Comment: yeah checked.the same code is here..have no clue wts happening

Comment: bro its... ans.substring(0,9) not ans.subString(0,9).

Comment: you may use ID of the tag to get element. also Please mark it as Answer. This will make you good reputation here and you will get more answer frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of the `data` property on a DOM element. Thanks to you, I learned it's a property on `textNode` elements (the same as `nodeValue`).

Also, using `getElementsByTagName` when the ID is available is unperformant.

`subString` doesn't work, it is `substring`. The case is important for methods as javascript is case sensitive (like most programming languages).

The other thing you're missing is an `else`. In your code, the `var newans...` will *always* be ran.

Here is something working:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ans = document.getElementById( 'message' ).textContent;
    if ( ans.length < 10 ) {
        alert( ans );
    }
    else {
        var newans = ans.substring( 0, 9 ) + '...';
    }
}
```

Comment: you can refer to the link to know firstchild.data http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=164474

Comment: innerHTML will work on more browsers and perhaps replace stupid with suboptimal or such. It is a noob.